# Limit of integral function with $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ as extrema

Tags: integration, limits

I have the following integral function:

$$ F(x) = \int_{x}^{2x} \frac{1}{1 + t \log(t)} dt$$
The domain of $F$ is $(0,\infty)$. I want to calculate the limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} F(x) = ? $$

I looked online but I could only find limit with only a function of x in the upper integral and not in both, so I am not sure on what I should do here. Any tips?

Comment: You could maybe rewrite it as difference of two $\int_{0}^{2x} \cdot dt - \int_{0}^x \cdot dt$, but with some risk you may end up with $\infty - \infty$ limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that, by the [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), for $x>0$,
$$\int_{x}^{2x} \frac{dt}{1 + t \log(t)} =\frac{2x-x}{1 + t_x \log(t_x)} $$
for some $t_x\in (x,2x)$.

Comment: Mmmm, then I take the limit with x going to infinity which makes this infinity?

Comment: @qcc101 Well, you took the wrong direction. Another try? Note that the denominator $1+t_x\log(t_x)$ goes to infinity too. Which is faster?

Comment: @qcc101 Notice that $t_x$ also varies with $x.$

Comment: Ohh I see, It goes to 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It suffices to bound above by the largest value in the integral

$$0\le\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{2x}\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t\log(t)}\le\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{2x}\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+x\log(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x{1+x\log(x)}=0$$

since the integrand is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: This is simply beautiful art!